# Routing between processing rule in DataPower

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

I have one MPGW which has 4 processing fule specific to 2 applications.

Processing rule request1, Processing rule request2, Processing rule response1 and Processing rule response2.

There are 2 flows. Application1 directly interacting with Processing rule request2 for which I don't have issues.

Application2 flow is interacting with Processing rule request1 in which I convert the message, URI, and route to Processing rule request2. Until this I am fine. My problem is how to reroute the message from Processing rule response2 to Processing rule response 1 specific to Application2.

Is there any way to reroute without touching the Processing rule response2?

Answer (score 1):

I think rerouting from one rule to another is not a good practise and I think even not well possible. Maybe this forth and back is better handled by either leveraging Call Processing Rule actions (reusable rules) or by a chained service approach?

Answer (score 0):

As August said, use chained services or move your "convert" into a "reusable service" (i.e. an XML Firewall in Loopback) and use only one rule in MPGW.

The other approach would be to use Conditional Actions or build a "smarter" routing solution using GWS, again then only using one Request- and on Response- rule.